# Rails Send 2 different emails from one mailer function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

I have a need to do so, because it seems logical to me:

```
def notification(vehicle) 
   @vehicle = vehicle

   mail(:to => @vehicle.owner.email_address, :template_name => "n_o")
   mail(:to => @vehicle.booker.email_address, :template_name => "n_b")
```

end

The problem is: I'm receiving only the **last** e-mail. So, in my example above, only the booker would receive the email and nothing is being sent to the owner.

What is the problem ? How to solve it ? Should I create two separate mailing functions, like notification_owner(vehicle) and notification_booker(vehicle), or there is a simplier solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437270/send-to-multiple-recipients-in-rails-with-actionmailer

Comment: Thank you. But that isn't exactly what I have here

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So, silly me, I forgot to mention that I'm dealing with delayed_jobs gem. So, the problem was, that I forgot to specify the ".deliver!" action after each "mail" function.

So, it should look like this:

```
mail(:to => @vehicle.owner.email_address, :template_name => "n_o").deliver!
mail(:to => @vehicle.booker.email_address, :template_name => "n_b").deliver!
```

But still. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def notification(vehicle,template_name) 
  @vehicle = vehicle
  mail(:to => @vehicle.owner.email_address, :template_name => template_name)
end


Mailer.notification(@vehicle,"n_o").deliver 
Mailer.notification(@vehicle,"n_b").deliver
```

Comment: Why would I have identical templates ? These e-mail's content is different for owner and booker.

Comment: OK. I got the idea. Will give it a try.