# Rails send 2 emails in one mailer function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I'm trying to send 2 emails on the same function but after send the log show

> An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message
>   smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address

if i remove one email works, and everything is configured ok.

someone can know about this issue?

```
def dispute_confirmation(dispute)
    @dispute = dispute


    mail(to: @dispute.buyer.email, subject: 'Reclamação Aberta', &:html)

     mail(to: @dispute.seller.email, subject: 'Comprador abriu uma Reclamação', &:html)


  end
```

Comment: this got nothing to do with sending two emails, as i can see, it can't deliver even 1, you need to fix that and you can send multiple emails too.

Comment: How do you call you mailer method?

Comment: This error is if one of your emails is blank. Have you verified buyer.email and seller.email are present?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an underscore in there instead of a period.

```
def dispute_confirmation(dispute)
  @dispute = dispute

  mail(to: @dispute.buyer.email, subject: 'Reclamação Aberta', &:html)
  mail(to: @dispute.seller.email, subject: 'Comprador abriu uma Reclamação', &:html)
end
```

Comment: Hello @chrisxrobertson, thank you, i changed this error and the same,
is not possible to send 2 emails on the same function in rails?

Comment: I'm not sure why that doesn't work, sorry. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/14727042/1576860